# Linear Algebra : Basis of quadratic equations?

Tags: linear-algebra

I am struggling with Linear Algebra lately , specifically , finding the basis of a set of quadratic equations.

question goes like this : B = {P1 = (1+X^3) ; P2 = (2X+X^2+X^3) P3 = (1-X^2) P4 = (2+X+X^3) , find if B is a basis in the vectorial space of R^<=3

Basically finding if it's components are linearly independent, but how do I treat/transform P1,P2,P3,P4 into vectors ?

I've looked online and couldn't find anything similar.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE.  It would improve your Question to clarify what the vector space is that $B$ might be a basis for.  [Mathematical notation](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) can be properly "typeset" in posts here, which make them more readable.

Comment: Note that $P_1$ and $P_4$ are not quadratic.

Comment: Sorry , I forgot to mention , set of quadratic/cubic equations.

Comment: They are vectors in the coefficients, not the variable. I think of polynomial vectors as an alternative labeling for the coeeffecients. So if I have some vector $(a,b,c)$ I could instead write this as $a + bx + cx^2$ where the power of $x$ indicated the position of the coefficients. Changing basis can result in different polynomials but the basic are essentially the same.

Answer (score 0):

How do I transform polynomials into vectors?

Polynomials ARE vectors!

If a collection of objects satisfy the axioms of a vector space (i.e. have a well defined concepts of addition and scalar multiplication) they form a vector space.

However, you might look at the coeficients of the polynomial and it will look very much like the vectors you are familiar with in $\mathbb R^4$

i.e.

$P_1 = (1,0,0,1), P_2 = (0,2,1,1), P_3 = (1,0,-1,0), P_4 = (2,1,0,1)$

Whether you convert them to this form or not.

They form a basis if:
Polynomials of degree 3 or less indeed form a vector space.  The proposed basis vectors span the space. And, they are linearly independent.